# How to render data on submit in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple form on child component A.  On submit I'm passing the data from the form to the parent component and storing the data in state..  I want to then move this data to a different child, child component B.(the sibling of A)

I'm having trouble getting the data to be rendered on submit in component B.  I'm not sure how to trigger the rendering on submit or how to pass this information via props on submit.

Here is the Parent

```js
class Msg extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.storeInput = this.storeInput.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            msg: ''
        };
    }

    storeInput (d) {
        this.setState({
            name: d.name,
            msg: d.msg
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className='msgContainer'>
                <Input 
                    passBack={this.storeInput}/>
                <Output />
            </div>     
        )
    }
}
```

Here is Component A

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            msg: ''
        };
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.passBack(this.state);
    }

    render () {
        const name = this.state.name;
        const msg = this.state.msg;

        return (
            <div className='form-container'>
                <form action="">
                    <label htmlFor="">name</label>
                    <input 
                      name='name'
                      value={name}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      type='text'></input>
    
                    <label htmlFor="">message</label>
                    <textarea 
                      name='msg'
                      value={msg}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      rows='5' cols='80'></textarea>
    
                    <input 
                      onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                      type='submit'></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is Component B

```js
class Output extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return(
            <div className='output'>
                
            </div>
        )
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you see that's wrong with it

Comment: There are two `render` methods. One of them ends abruptly. Given it's component class, it isn't posted entirely. Left alone there should be at least 2 of them. Considering that you have a problem with specific code, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Code sample has been changed to reflect all 3 relative components in their entirety.

Comment: When `state` changes component re-renders. I am not sure what could be the problem but trying something like this  `<Output  whatever={this.state}/>` and then in component B, `console.log(this.props.whatever)` should give you your new state or maybe I got the question wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the state as props to Output like so:

Parent Component:

```
import React from 'react';

import Input from './Input';
import Output from './Output';

class Msg extends React.Component {
  state = { name: '', msg: '' };

  storeInput = d => {
    this.setState({ name: d.name, msg: d.msg });
  };

  render() {
    // destructure the state
    const { name, msg } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="msgContainer">
        <Input passBack={this.storeInput} />
        {/* pass the state as props to Output */}
        <Output name={name} msg={msg} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Msg;
```

Input.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Input extends React.Component {
  state = { name: '', msg: '' };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.passBack(this.state);
    this.setState({ name: '', msg: '' }); // clear up the input after submit
  };

  render() {
    const { name, msg } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="form-container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="">name</label>
          <input
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="text"
          />
          <label htmlFor="">message</label>
          <textarea
            name="msg"
            value={msg}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            rows="5"
            cols="80"
          />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Input;
```

Output.js

```
import React from 'react';

// destructure the props coming in from Msg
// no need for a class-based component

const Output = ({ name, msg }) => (
  <div className="output">
    <div>Output</div>
    <p>{name}</p>
    <p>{msg}</p>
  </div>
);

export default Output;
```

**Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/c8th67zn/**

Comment: Would be helpful to explain the changes rather than just post some code!

Comment: Are you sure doing   `const { name, msg } = this.state;` in render a good practise?

Comment: @SakoBu  This is the solution to the question as asked, so thank you for the insight.  I noticed though that when I submit the form again, the previous data is erased and re-render with the new input.  

Would I need a different structure in order to keep all submits until page close/reload?

Comment: @4cody - Yes... You could consider storing the state in the parent as an array and each submit appends a new msg to that array...

Comment: @4cody This is probably what you want... : https://jsfiddle.net/h3xo57na/1/

Comment: I didn’t mean it like that, but posting a solution code without explaining is discouraged!